# Input data directly through Power BI published report

Tags: io, powerbi

Is there any workaround to input data directly through PBI in published report? I would like the users to input comments to the graphs. It would be fantastic if the user could do that directly in PBI report, below the chart.

I can see on official PBI Ideas For Improvement page that these features are developers' dreams to be voted:

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/9414921-input-fields

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/13820190-power-bi-online-query-parameters?page=1&per_page=20

Maybe there is some hidden workaround to that which slips out beyond the attention of Microsoft team? Maybe there is some visual, or script in R which allows sending data anywhere where it can be stored - SQL Server, Sharepoint?

Here is very inspiring hint example of IO made in R - passing clicks coordinates done in PBI to SQL and then back to Power BI:
https://medium.com/@dr_eldersveld/r-visuals-in-power-bi-beyond-plots-74c618f2e6f3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely possible.

You can create a [PowerApps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/) (which basically allows you to connect to any (or most) data sources) and then embed the app in Power BI with [PowerApps custom visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/powerapps-custom-visual). It may take some effort but the use case is unlimited.

The following shows a simple example on how to save and show user input in PowerApps:

[image: powerapps]

The `TextInput1` accepts user input, the save `icon1` have `OnSelect` set to `Set(comment, TextInput1.Text)` to save the text from the text input to the variable `comment`; and the `Label1` shows the `comment` value.

When you edit the Power BI report on Power BI Web, add the `PowerApps Custom Visual` from the marketplace, and choose the app you just created, this is what will happen:

[image: input]

[image: output]

Note that this is just an example and it won't persist user input upon refresh. If you want to save the comment to show it to other users, you'll have to modify the app and connect it to a data source, create a table to store the comment, update its value with user input, etc..

Comment: Your answer is very promising. Could you please bring me closer to the point? I have read the article under your link. I have not found anything which brought me closer to I/O through PBI visuals. The picture/video you provided is not relevant in any way to input data as I want i.e. "text field".

Comment: What exactly do you want? A static text field for comment?

Comment: Not a static field. Dynamic. User sees graph and below the graph he inputs a comment to it. Different user may see the comment.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin I'm afraid too many details are needed to arrive at a full solution... Think of it as the equivalent of `How to create a web application to accept, store and display input from users`. PowerApps provides an easier way for you to create an application (web/Android/iOS) without writing native codes. And the fact that it has integration with Power BI enables them to communicate and share data from one to other (Although in this case it's not needed because you just want to save a user input). I've modified the answer and hope you'll understand more about what's going on.

Comment: I appreciate you answer.

Comment: Guys, I just wanted to thank you for discussing this topic, providing an answer and making me laugh (ugly chart). Cheers & have a great day :-)