# Commenting on reports in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Is there any way to achieve real time commenting(for e.g. edit comment, post comment , delete comment) on reports in Power BI which can be visible to the users that have access to the report?

Answer (score 0):

This link on input data through PBI visual might be helpful.
[Input data directly through Power BI published report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51611281/input-data-directly-through-power-bi-published-report)

General idea is to use Power Apps.